# How do i create a test Suite in python unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

i tried:

```
def buildTestSuite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for testcase in glob.glob('src/testsuite/test_*.py'):
        module = os.path.splitext(testcase)[0]
        print module
        print type(module)
        suite.addTest(__import__(module).buildTestSuite())
    return suite
```

but i get eror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtests.py", line 63, in ?
    results = main()
  File "runtests.py", line 57, in main
    results = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(buildTestSuite())
  File "runtests.py", line 53, in buildTestSuite
    suite.addTest(__import__(module).buildTestSuite())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'buildTestSuite'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def buildTestSuite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for testcase in glob.glob('src/testsuite/test_*.py'):
        modname = os.path.splitext(testcase)[0]
        module=__import__(modname,{},{},['1'])
        suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(module))
    return suite
```

Comment: error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtests.py", line 64, in ?
    results = main()
  File "runtests.py", line 58, in main
    results = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(buildTestSuite())
  File "runtests.py", line 52, in buildTestSuite
    module =__import__(modname, fromlist='1')
TypeError: __import__() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: `__import__` accepts keyword arguments in Python2.6+ (at least). What version of Python are you using?

Comment: [I see](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release24-maint/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup). Instead of using `sys.modules`, I think `module=__import__(modname,{},{},['1'])` should work also.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
for t in glob.glob('src/testsuite/test_*.py'):
    try:
        # If the module defines a suite() function, call it to get the suite.
        mod = __import__(t, globals(), locals(), ['suite'])
        suitefn = getattr(mod, 'suite')
        suite.addTest(suitefn())
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        # else, just load all the test cases from the module.
        suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(t))
```

Comment: i get error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtests.py", line 76, in ?
    results = main()
  File "runtests.py", line 70, in main
    results = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(buildTestSuite())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/unittest.py", line 696, in run
    test(result)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable